# What marks the start of a new employment?

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts

I have started working in a new place, which I am not sure if I want to work because of many reasons, but I haven’t signed an agreement yet. It has been 2-3 days. If I leave this workplace, will they give me a P45?

What is considered the start of employment with a company?

Comment: related https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147496/how-can-i-negotiate-remote-work-due-to-my-phobia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I haven’t signed agreement yet

Less relevant than you might think - you've already entered into a contract of employment with them.

> If I leave this workplace, will they give me P45?

Yep. You've been employed there, even if only for a few days plus whatever notice period they make you serve (if any) and they have to pay you for that. Paying you means all the wonderful HMRC gubbins that come along with that and thus a P45.

> What make a start of employment with a company?

The commencement date as outlined in your offer/contract - in the absence of that or of any paperwork to the contrary it will be the first day you worked.

Comment: Oh, I thought signing agreement makes it valid. I been trying f this job but due to some concern and asthma I want to leave, but on a potential place I told them that I haven’t accepted the offer from them so if they hire me, I have to tell them I didn’t tell them the truth as I was trying out them?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work like that - if you've started working there then you've ..erm.. *started working there*. Most jobs have probationary periods or similar constructs (making it easy for both parties if they wish to end the relationship) but that doesn't make you any less *employed*.

Comment: @flux, Are you saying you've been working for free for these past two days? I very much doubt that. Or is that what you told them? "Guys, I just want to try this out. You do not have to pay me anything. I am just volunteering." Is that what you told them?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk no I didn’t tell such thing but I was under impression that till contract or HMRC form is filled it not official. Which I didn’t

Comment: @flux, Again, I know what you were thinking, but what you were thinking doesn't make any sense whatsoever. You're expecting to be paid for those two days? Aren't you? You were employed. End of story.